# Python Flask передать аргументы в запуск приложения

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

У меня есть приложение на Flask
Запуск происходит следующим образом

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=host,ssl_context=('root_ca.crt','root_ca.key'))
```

В консоли

```
python3 app.py
```

Но мне бы хотелось запускать через

```
flask run
```

Но я не понимаю,как в аргументы отправить ssl_context
Может знает кто-нибудь?

Comment: Попробуйте $ flask run --cert=root_ca.crt --key=root_ca.key

Comment: Или так flask run --cert root_ca.crt --key root_ca.key